# How to use LINQ to iterate and display a list of objects in groups

Tags: c#, linq

I have this `list`: which I need to display so that information for each artist is listed under that respective artist.

What I have tried so far list the same data under each artist.

```
public class Artist
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Car { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public List<Artist> Profile()
    {
        var artistList = new List<Artist>();

        // Artist: 1

        artistList.Add(new Artist() { Name = "Nick Cage", Car = "Corvette", ID = 1 });
        artistList.Add(new Artist() { Name = "Nick Cage", Car = "Porsche 718", ID = 1 });
        artistList.Add(new Artist() { Name = "Nick Cage", Car = "Audi", ID = 1 });

        // Artist: 2

        artistList.Add(new Artist() { Name = "Ryan Rynolds", Car = "Lotus", ID = 2 });
        artistList.Add(new Artist() { Name = "Ryan Rynolds", Car = "Alfa Romeo", ID = 2 });
        artistList.Add(new Artist() { Name = "Ryan Rynolds", Car = "Jaguar", ID = 2 });

        return artistList;

    }
}
```

Using a `Windows Form` `MessageBox` I need to display the data so that the result is arranged like this when the `MessageBox` is loaded.

```
Nick Cage
ID 1
Porsche 718
Audi
BMW

Ryan Rynolds
ID 2
Lotus
Alfa Romeo
Jaguar
```

For this demonstration, I have all the code in a single method in the form's code behind:

```
    private readonly Artist _artist = null;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _artist = new Artist();
    }

    private void DisplayArtist()
    {
        StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();

        var group = _artist.Profile().GroupBy(t => 
        t.Name).Select(grp => grp.FirstOrDefault());

        foreach (var person in group)
        {
            content.Append(person.Name);
            content.AppendLine();

            // Append names to list


            foreach (var profile in group)
            {
              // Append profile to list
              // Tried using second loop but not getting expected results
            }

            content.AppendLine();

        }

        DialogResult result1 = 
            MessageBox.Show(content.ToString(),
            "Artist Profile", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayArtist();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are almost there. First you group with something like this:

```
var grouped = p.GroupBy(a => new { a.ID, a.Name });
```

(I used the combination of name and id so I can retrieve both from the key)

Then you can loop through each group:

```
foreach (var g in grouped)
{
    Console.WriteLine(g.Key.Name);
    Console.WriteLine(g.Key.ID);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", g.Select(c => c.Car)));
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Here I'm just writing to the console, but you could assemble a string for a message box or whatever you are doing with it.

Comment: Console not found :)

Answer (score 2):

Don't do the `Select(grp => grp.FirstOrDefault())` that's removing all but the first item in each grouping. Then when you iterate over the result you'll have a `IGrouping` that has a `Key` property with the name and that can itself be iterated over to get each individual artist object in that group.

```
var people = _artist.Profile().GroupBy(t => t.Name);

foreach (var person in people)
{
    content.AppendLine(person.Key); // The name of the person

    foreach (var profile in person)
    {
        content.AppendLine(profile.Car); //The name of each car
    }
}
```

Comment: They'd still need to pull out the `ID` for the group too.

Comment: Thanks everyone!!

Answer (score 0):

There many ways to achieve what you asked. If you still want to use your `_artist.Profile().GroupBy(t => t.Name);` code then here is one of them:

```
var group = _artist.Profile().GroupBy(t =>
            t.Name);

var result = string.Join("\n", group.Select(a =>
{
      var carStr = a.Select(c => c.Car);
      return $"{a.FirstOrDefault()?.Name}\n{a.FirstOrDefault()?.ID}\n{string.Join("\n", carStr)}";
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way (and I really think that its a better overall design) is to create your object Artist like this:

```
public class Artist
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> Cars { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public List<Artist> Profile()
    {
        var artistList = new List<Artist>();

        // Artist: 1
        artistList.Add(new Artist()
        {
            ID = 1,
            Name = "Nick Cage",
            Car = new List<string>
            {
                "Corvette",
                "Porsche 718",
                "Audi"
            }
        });

        // Artist 2
        artistList.Add(new Artist()
        {
            ID = 2,
            Name = "Ryan Rynolds",
            Car = new List<string>
            {
                "Lotus",
                "Alfa Romeo",
                "Jaguar"
            }
        });

        return artistList;

    }
}
```

Advantages:

- No data redundancy
- Less memory (of course, only noticeable on huge lists)
- No need for grouping
- More sense in the real world, because there is only one artist named Nick Cage, and he has a list of cars

To achieve what you want, just do:

```
foreach(Artist a in artistList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(a.Name);
    Console.WriteLine(a.ID);

    foreach(string car in a.Cars)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(car);
    }
}
```